# Pgfplot with logarithmic x-axis to zero

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm busy creating a learning curve, however I am unable to get my plots (blue) and my baseline (black) to zero. I use a logarythmic x-axis with fixed tick points. When i use `xmin > 0`, my whole plot shifts to the right. Does anyone have an idea?

[image: Learning curve in current situation.]

The code i use:

```
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
title={Learning curve},
xlabel={Training examples},
ylabel={F-score},
xmin=0, xmax=7600,
ymin=0.0, ymax=0.7,
xtick={0,500,1000,2000,4000,7600},
ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7},
log ticks with fixed point,
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
legend pos=south east,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
color=blue,
mark=square,
thick,
]
coordinates {
(0,0)(500,0.45)(1000,0.47)(2000,0.49)(4000,0.52)(7600,0.63)
};

\addplot[
mark=none,
thin,
]
coordinates {
 (0,0.42)(500,0.42)(1000,0.42)(2000,0.42)(4000,0.42)(7600,0.42)
};

\end{semilogxaxis}
```

Comment: You want to use `xmin=0`? On a logarithmic axis, you can't - the log of zero is undefined. You'll have to use a sufficiently small number instead, e.g. 1E-6, 1E-9, etc.

Comment: Thanks @darthbith, however when i use xmin=1 or another small number (1E-6), the plot lines shift to the right strangely.

Comment: Yes, of course they do - you're setting the xmin way to the left. What is your goal? You cannot have a zero valued point on a logarithmic axis - it is mathematically impossible. You'll have to do some other processing, e.g. manually taking the log of all the points except zero and plotting them on a linear axis (with properly set ticks)

Comment: First, you will need an infinitely large sheet of paper... ;-)